# Imagemagick via matplotlib appears to be truncating GIF length on creation

Tags: python, matplotlib, imagemagick

I'm currently using the python matplotlib to create some animated graphs and then using ImageMagick to turn these into gifs.

This is the line of code that creates the animation:

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func = init, interval = 20, blit = True)
```

matplotlib happily animates these using `plt.show()`

When I export it as a gif I get no errors, a gif is created that reflects what's displayed with `plot.show()` but it's only the first ~25% of the animation (1.1MB).

This is the code for exporting it:

```
anim.save(filepath/name, writer = 'imagemagick')
```

I've hunted high and low, but can't find anything that would indicate why this might be happening.  There doesn't seem to be a limit on filesize or frames configured anywhere that I'm hitting.  If one of the images created was corrupted I'd expect the `plt.show()` animation to fail and/or error messages to be received.

Any pointers gratefully received - I can't find the thread to unravel this one!

Comment: Post a link to your gif animation file so that others can examine and test with it.

Comment: We don't need the file, but a runnable code that reproduces this, as well as information about your setup, os, versions etc.

Comment: Actually, what's happening is simply that you create an infinite animation. However, people usually don't want to save infinite data on disk, which is why saving is limited. The solution will depend on what you want to show, with how many frames and what your `animate` function actually does. That is all unknown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On investigation it looks as though there is a default of 100 frames for the save function, unless otherwise specified.  I couldn't see this in the documentation, but used a count on the iterate() function to see how many times it was being called.

This limit does not apply for the `plt.show()` function, hence the discrepancy occurring.

Adding the number of data points to the frames parameter fixes this issue. i.e.

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = data_points, init_func = init, interval = 20, blit = True)
anim.save(filepath/name, writer = 'imagemagick')
```

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying to get past the 100 frames cutoff for a couple of days and this solved it. I still needed a third party package (GIMP) to stop the auto-loop behaviour

Comment: Also wanted to say thank you, this helped me just now!